# using grep lookup/cut function instead of source to load config file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspbian, debian-based

I have a script that I'm using now that loads all my config variables in by means of `source` command. It's simple quick and effective. But i understand that it's not a very secure option.

I've read that I can use the `$include` directive to achieve the same results. Is that any different or safer than `source` or are they essentially the same?

As a final alternative if the above two options are not safe ones, I'm trying to understand a `lookup` function I found in a shell scripting book. It basically used `grep`, a delimiter and `cut` to perform a variable name lookup from the file and retrieve the value. This seems safe and I can use it to modify my scripts.

It almost works as is. I think I just need to change the delimiter to "=" from $TAB but I'm not sure how it works or if it even will.

**My config file format:**

```
Param=value
```

**Sample function (from notes)**

```
lookup() {
   grep "^$1$TAB" "$2" | cut -f2
}
```

**Usage:**

```
lookup [options] KEY FILE
-f sets field delimiter
-k sets the number of field which has key
-v specifies which field to return
```

I'm using Debian version of Raspbian Jessie Lite in case that matters on syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `grep` and `cut` you should consider using `awk` that can do both search and cut operations based on a given delimiter easily:

```
lookup() {
   key="$1"
   filename="$2"

   awk -F= -v key="$key" '$1 == key{print $2}' "$filename"

   # use this awk if = can be present in value part as well
   # awk -v key="^$key=" '$0 ~ key && sub(key, "")' "$filename"
}
```

This can be called as:

```
lookup search configfile.txt
```

`-F=` sets delimiter as `=` for awk command.

Also note that `$1` and `$2` inside single quotes are columns #1 and #2 and one shouldn't be confused with positional shell variables `$1`, `$2` etc.

You should look into `getopts` to make it accept `-f`, `-k` etc type arguments.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is `$include` an option?

Comment: There is no `$include` directive in any of the standard shell utilities. You can of course call other shell scripts from inside your shell scripts by using `bash ./otherscript.sh`

Comment: But then that runs a subshell.  The Bash equivalent to `$include` in some other languages is definitely `source`.

Comment: This is broken if the value contains an equals sign.  Perhaps `grep "^$key=" "${2-configfile.txt}" | cut -d= -f2-` would actually be better.

Comment: Though presence of `=` in value is not mentioned in question but if that is indeed the case then also `grep+cut` can be avoided using `awk -v key="^$key=" '$0 ~ key && sub(key, "")' "$filename"`

Comment: Assuming that the keys are alphanumeric (or at least don't contain a`/`), `sed` can work well: `sed -n "s/^$key *= *//p" "$filename"` **EDIT:** This sed based approach can easily become recipe for shell injection. DO NOT USE THIS.